# C++ Pointer function to other class function

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I need help with passing a function pointer on C++. I can't linkage one function for a class to other function. I will explain. Anyway I will put a code resume of my program, it is much larger than the code expose here but for more easier I put only the part I need to it works fine.

I have one class (`MainSystem`) and inside I have an object pointer to the other class (`ComCamera`). The last class is a `SocketServer`, and I want when the socket received any data, it sends to the linkage function to MainSystem.

ComCamera is a resource Shared with more class and I need to associate the functions ComCamera::vRecvData to a MainSystem::vRecvData or other function of other class for the call when receive data and send de data to the function class associate.

Can Anyone help to me?

**EDDITED - SOLUTION BELOW**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>  
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>
#include <unistd.h>

using std::string;

class ComCamera {
public:
    std::function<void(int, std::string)> vRecvData;

    void vLinkRecvFunction(std::function<void(int, std::string)> vCallBack) {
        this->vRecvData = vCallBack;
    }

    void vCallFromCamera() {
        this->vRecvData(4, "Example");
    };
};

class MainSystem {
private:
    ComCamera *xComCamera;
public:
    MainSystem(ComCamera *xComCamera) {
        this->xComCamera = xComCamera;
        this->xComCamera->vLinkRecvFunction([this](int iChannelNumber, std::string sData) {vRecvData(iChannelNumber, sData); });
    }

    void vRecvData(int iNumber, string sData) {
        std::cout << "RECV Data From Camera(" + std::to_string(iNumber) + "): " << sData << std::endl;
    };
};

int main(void) {
    ComCamera xComCamera;
    MainSystem xMainSystem(&xComCamera);

    xComCamera.vCallFromCamera();

    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

> MainSystem RECV Data From Camera(4): Example

Comment: This is far too much code. Please try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The signature of `MainSystem::vRecvData()` doesn't match the one required in `ComCamera:: vLinkRecvFunction()`. The latter expects a _function_ pointer but you provide a _method_ pointer. (This is a significant difference.) It would work e.g. if you make `MainSystem::vRecvData()` `static`. (Static methods can be used like free functions as they can be called without an object.)

Comment: Hi @Scheff. I need not static function because I need to use with an instance of an object, because i have different instances of object. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I suspected that you don't want a `static` function. However, `ComCamera::vLinkRecvFunction()` expects a function pointer. So, you cannot pass a method pointer nor a lambda with capture. It's simply a type mismatch (and wouldn't work even if you do some crazy type casting).

Comment: Usually, when an API offers callback function registration it allows some kind of client data but in this case it is missing. Either the `ComCamera` authors simply forgot it or they had good reasons to not do so.

Comment: And btw. C++ provides `std::function`. With `std::function<void(int, string)>` (instead of `void(*)(int, string)`) you had the freedom to register anything with matching signature: static functions, member functions, virtual member functions, and capturing lambdas. (`std::function` provides much more flexibilty though on the cost of performance.)

Comment: Hi @Scheff ComCamera is an own API, I can change anything to make it more usable for my purpose, but I don't know why I need to modify to do this.

Comment: Then the last comment concerning [**`std::function`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is probably interesting for you.

Comment: You may also consider that `ComCamera` may support multiple receivers. For this, you can wrap `std::function` in a `std::vector` where registration pushs to. Now, this becomes something like a simple signal-slot concept.

Comment: Hi @Scheff again, I tried with `std::function` but I can't make it work with that, I will go to edit the post with a example more readable to test.

Comment: There appeared already the answer of [SkepticalEmpiricist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037358/7478597) similar like I had done it. May be, I can motivate him to show it without `bind`. (I hate `bind` since I was doomed to use it in `sigc++` in absence of lambdas which were introduced in C++11.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `ComCamera::vRecvData` be of *type* `std::function<void(int, std::string)>` and then have `ComCamera::vLinkRecvFunction()` be like this:

```
void ComCamera::vLinkRecvFunction(std::function<void(int, std::string)> callBack)
{
    this->vRecvData = callBack;
}
```

and have `MainSystem` *constructor* be like this:

```
MainSystem::MainSystem(ComCamera *xComCamera)
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    this->xComCamera = xComCamera;
    this->xComCamera->vLinkRecvFunction([this](int iNumber, std::string sData){vRecvData(number, sData);});
}
```

Still though the original question has way too much code to go through friend.

Comment: I just made some advertising for your answer. But, I would like it even more if you could add an alternative with lambdas (instead of `bind`). (I hate `bind` as already stated in my above comment.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff OK friend, I made the edit you request, as I can definitely identify with your aversion here : )

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist, Thank you, It works perfectly, for the next time I will try to put less code for my question.

Comment: @Redhunt You could easily edit the question to remove much of the code and leave only a few short blocks relevant to the question itself (about the function pointer) -- that way this question will not be closed and so it could serve other people better, if they encounter such a problem like yours.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I edited the question, Please review if you see correctly edition. Thanks for all of your support.

Comment: @Redhunt Definitely fine now as far as I can see. Cheers : )

Answer (score 1):

Here what you want :

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;

class A; //forward declare A
class B{
    public:
    void (A::*ptr)(int x); //Only declare the pointer because A is not yet defined.
};

class A{
    public:
    void increase_by(int x){
        a+=x;
    } // this function will be pointed by B's ptr
    int a = 0; // assume some data in a;
    B b; // creating B inside of A;
    void analyze(int y){ 
        (*this.*(b.ptr))(y);
    }   // Some function that analyzes the data of A or B; Here this just increments A::a through B's ptr           
};

int main(){
    A a; // creates A
    cout<<a.a<<"\n"; // shows initial value of a
    a.b.ptr = &A::increase_by; // defines the ptr that lies inside of b which inturns lies inside a
    a.analyze(3); // calls the initialize method
    (a.*(a.b.ptr))(3); // directly calls b.ptr to change a.a
    cout<<a.a; // shows the value after analyzing
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be :

> 0
>
> 6

I still don't get why would you do something like this. But maybe this is what you wanted as per your comments.
To know more read this wonderful [PDF](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://umich.edu/%7Eeecs381/handouts/Pointers_to_memberfuncs.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjc2Ny744zdAhWFe30KHXWoBYkQFjABegQICxAE&usg=AOvVaw3EBnQB7eR3awO3ByQQglb2).

Comment: Hi @coder3101, thanks for your post, but my problem is `class B` is object inside `class A` and I need a function to call from `class B` with data to `class A` function where I going to analyze data

Comment: @Redhunt Updated